# Populating an N-ary Tree- Java

Tags: java, tree

I'm implementing a N-ary tree in Java; each node can have as many nodes as possible. The problem comes when I try to build a tree. 
I have a function that recursively creates a tree of a specific height, and assigns the child nodes based from a List of Nodes. When I call the function the root node dose not contain any data; it returns a null once it is finished. I have never implemented an N-ary tree so I'm somewhat sure of the implementation, any pointers on it would really be appreciated!

```
//Creates a tree 
void createTree(int height) throws InvalidMoveException,   
  Modified_Tree.InvalidMoveException {
    root = new ListNode();
    root = populateTree(moves.root,height,true,0);  
}

 //Function called by Create tree to populate the tree
 //It takes in a ListNode, an int height that determines the height of the tree, 
 //and a boolean, which is used
 //To know whether the node is a black piece/max or a white piece/min

 public ListNode populateTree(ListNode root, int height, boolean black, int score) 
  {

    ListNode node = root;
     List<ListNode> nodes = new List<ListNode>(10);

     //Sets the size of List in node to the int taken
              node.setChildNumber(nodes.size());

    //return if reached the pre-maximum height
    if(height == 1){

        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){

            //Add the child to the last node
            node.addChild(nodes.get(i));

        }

        return node;
    }

    else{

              for(int j =0; j < node.getChildNumber(); j++){
      node = populateTree(node.getChildAt(j),height-1,!black,score);

        }   
    }
    return node;
 }
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: One thing to add, This tree is used for a game tree where each node contains a move. Referee is another class that contains the legal_moves, and simulates a movement on the board game. A listNode contains many things that hold a variable, AND a List of ListNode. Nodify in the if(height == 1) just converts a move into a ListNode.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the problem? Right now it looks like your code is intertwined with some business-logic. Can you reproduce this in a general manner?

Comment: Sure thing, let me see what I can do

Comment: That should be more understandable, sorry about that!

Comment: no worries. I'll see if I can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
List<ListNode> nodes = new List<ListNode>(10);
```

First, I assume you meant `new ArrayList<ListNode>(10);` or some other concrete implementation of `List<T>`. Second, the argument `10` only ensures that you will have `10` locations initially. It *does not* mean that you will have `10` `ListNode` instances automatically initialized inside `nodes`. Then you have:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
        //Add the child to the last node
        node.addChild(nodes.get(i));
    }
```

This loop will never execute because `nodes.size()` is zero due to it not containing any nodes at all. So you need to initialized your list with `ListNode` instances first.

Comment: Yes, i did mean ArrayList, that probably just slipped while i was changing everything. So even thought i initialize ListNode to have 10 locations, size will still be zero? Does that mean that it actually has to have something inside rather than available locations?

Comment: I had the idea that ArrayList was kinda like a vector in c++. Having never actually programmed in java kinda makes some of these containers unknown to how they really work.

Comment: @Oswl Ah, yeah I can see how that can be a source of confusion. In Java when you initialize a container, that's all you're doing. It doesn't automatically populate it with instances of the type. If you think about it, it may not even be possible because it might be the case that the type doesn't have a 0-arg constructor.

Comment: So if, lets say nodes, which is the List<ListNode> had already some values in the container, the code would work? Is the implementation of building this type of tree correct?

Comment: @Oswl, I'm not entirely sure how you're looking to build the tree. Are you looking to build an n-ary tree of arbitrary height h? What is the relationship between parent and child nodes?

Comment: Yes on the height. A ListNode is just an element, with a List of List Node, so a parent will have its child nodes in the List, and each child will have a List as well.

Comment: So my implementation is to get the first node in the List, traverse the tree, by passing that first child of the parent node, and subtracting from height, and stopping when height is 1; Once its one, it should stop at the parent of the bottom nodes. When thats the case, I add the last bottom children nodes to the parent node, and return

Comment: but maybe i should change the node=populate... to node.addChild(populate...)

Comment: @Oswl Isn't an implicit height already defined by the relationship between parent and child nodes? I don't see how you can define a tree of arbitrary height, when that height is defined by the structure of the tree. You can only have one or the other :) Unless you are trying to re-balance a tree/heap or something while maintaining a consistent property.